# use illuminate/pagination outside laravel

Tags: php, laravel, illuminate

I try to use `laravel pagination` in my custom CMS

the `illuminate/pagination` work, but not properly

this code for my controller work

```php
       $cats= Category::paginate(2);
```

but when i want to calling the pagination link in this code in blade engine

```php
{{$cats->links()}}

or 

{!! $cats->links() !!}

or 

{{$cats->render()}}
```

I get this error

```
call_user_func() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, no array or string given (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\gitrepo\mvcframwork\resources\view\admin\products\category.blade.php)
```

[image]

git project url
https://github.com/mohammadZx/mvcframwork/tree/log

you can check project in github on log branch

I think this problem belongs to `laravel pagination service provider` but still i don't know how register laravel providers or fix this problem

Comment: At first you call it `$categories` and then you call it `$cats` ...

Comment: I'm sorry. I edited. in view i calling in view with ```cats``` key but error still has

Answer (score 0):

you have to register `PaginationSerivceProvider`.
follow `PaginationSerivceProvider` in `regsiter` method and do required actions

Or

go to `LengthAwarePaginator.php` file and refactor a blade or view handler for this method with contained property
you should know below method have all pagination system and just need to require in view handler

```php
public function render($view = null, $data = [])
    {
        return static::viewFactory()->make($view ?: static::$defaultView, 
          array_merge($data, [
            'paginator' => $this,
            'elements' => $this->elements(),
         ]));
    }
```